# Node.js HTML page error 404 while getting javascript

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, http-status-code-404

Im working with node.js and I wanted my HTML file to GET javascript files.

This is the file i'm running with node.js called `server.js`:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Very simple code made to host `index.html`. This HTML file has some script tags:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./A.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="./B.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="./C.js"></script>
```

And the problem is that when i run `server.js` and I go to the browser I get this errors on the console:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/A.js 
GET http://localhost:3000/B.js 
GET http://localhost:3000/C.js 404 (Not Found)
```

[404 error not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcxeE.png)

The files are all in the same directory and I don't understand why it doesn't get the scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `server.js` does not know how to handle anything besides requests for the root page. (Even http://localhost:3000/index.html will fail with a 404.)

Add the [`express.static` middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) to serve files from a directory:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);

express.static('public')

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Now any files in the `public` folder will be served as you intend. (Move your *.js files to a sub-folder named `public`)

See the [HyperDev default project template](https://hyperdev.com/#!/project/orchid-beggar) for a good interactive example of this in action.

Comment: yes thank you :) the only thing missing in the code you put was to declare a var express = require('express') and then app = express()

Comment: @NunoMiguelSilva: ah.. fixed it~

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at the [Express](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)[1](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) Documentation for serving static files.

You're serving your index file with these lines:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
   res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
```

You can serve js files the same way or by putting them in a `public` folder and adding `app.use(express.static('public'))`.

Then you can reference them as `public/A.js`

Comment: On the server, the file will be `public/A.js`, but it should be referenced in the HTML as just `./A.js`