# node.js javascript file in html 404

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, webstorm

I just installed Webstorm and using Node.js, I do have a problem in one of my HTML pages.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type = "text/javascript" src = "../public/filename.js" ></script>
</head>

<body>
<input type = "button" onclick = "sayHello()" value = "Say Hello" />
</body>
</html>
```

When I run it, I do have:

```
untitled:server Listening on port 3000 +0ms
GET / 304 15.947 ms - -
GET /public/filename.js 404 917.751 ms - 1222
```

I tried to use the solution in this post :
[Node.js HTML page error 404 while getting javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40595535/node-js-html-page-error-404-while-getting-javascript)
but sadly it didn't work.

This is my app.js file :

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');


var indexRouter = require('./routes/index.js');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

express.static('public');


// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));
app.use(express.static('/public'));


app.use('/', indexRouter);


app.use('/users', usersRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

Project Structure:

[image]

Comment: You don't have a route to `/public/filename.js`. But you do have a static path set to `/public`. Change your URL to `/filename.js`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it work fine now !

Comment: Glad to help. Have fun.